# How to detect support for top level await in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, top-level-await

ECMAScript 2022 introduced await at the top level of a module. In older browser versions (eg Safari 14) it throws a syntax error. I would like to detect support for TLA so I can provide an alternative.

Since this is a syntax feature I tried to eval TLA in a try/catch-block. However this will always throw a syntax error, since await is only valid at the top level, not inside try and eval.

Comment: For syntax features, you're probably best transpiling your code (I'm assuming they handle TLA). That way the code that ends up running in the users browser will be the same and supported by both.